# Reading byte array from a SQL database through WCF - maxArrayLength issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service which is supposed to return a `List` to my client application. One of the columns in the database are `byte[]`. When I try to return this list of Object, I only get a `NetDispatcherFaultException` with this inner-exception:

> "The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while
>   reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the
>   MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used
>   when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 38697."

I have googled after this and found a that I should increase the `maxArrayLength` in the `web.config`, so I did:

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" 
         bindingConfiguration="CrudserviceBinding" />
</protocolMapping>

<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CrudserviceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800" >
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10242880"  
                          maxArrayLength="10242880" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**This is my app.config on the client side:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICrudService">
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" 
                              maxArrayLength="52428800" />
              </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/My.Project/CrudService.svc"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICrudService"
                      contract="MobileCrudService.ICrudService" 
                      name="BasicHttpBinding_ICrudService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I try this once more,  the WCF service returns the same exception. Can anybody explain how I should deal with this?

Comment: Did you apply this to both server and client configurations?

Comment: _the same exception_ - also with the same length (`16384`) ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, 16384.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the config file you have changed is the one is use? (eg, if you've changed the app.config, has the application been rebuilt, and is the file in the debug/release folder correct)?

Comment: OK, so your config is not applied.

Comment: @HaemEternal When I open my .config in the debug folder, my .dll file has the correct settings. It's a .dll file because it is a plugin to a bigger application.

Comment: _my .dll file has the correct settings_ does not compute. Can you list the exact name and location of the config in the question?

Comment: @HenkHolterman under my TFS folder: `Products/ProductName/Main/Source/Project_Name/bin/Debug/ProjectName.dll.config` This is the configuration for the client-side.

Comment: Do you use http or https to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MaksymStrukov I'm using the Http scheme.

Comment: A `dll.config` is normally not used. What is in the main config?

Comment: Config files for DLLs are irrelevant. All that matters is the config file for the host process. As for which one to change, you only need to change the client, because the issue is RECEIVING the data. Only the client is the one receiving the large data. And only worry about the setting it's complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the service in a class Library on the Client, make sure you are changing the actual Application .config file. Do not use

```
Products/ProductName/Main/Source/Project_Name/bin/Debug/ProjectName.dll.config
```

instead use

```
Products/ProductName/Main/Source/Project_EXE_Name/bin/Debug/YourExe.config
```